# pause meta refresh when the form is open

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, meta-tags

i have a simple html page which is getting refreshed every 15 seconds and there is one form where users can give his comments. but when users is typing comment the page gets refreshed as meta tag will refresh it in 15 secons. i want to pause meta refresh when the user has clicked on form and giving input in form . this is my meta tag and form.

```
   <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15;url=http://xyyyyyyy.com/testn.php">
```

here is form

```
     <form action="http://xtsss.com/testee.php" method="post" id="pc_form">
        <p>

      <div><input type="text" rows="15" style="width:800px" name="message" id="pc_message"></div>
        </p>
     <p>
       <input type="hidden" value="644" name="pid">

        <input type="hidden" value="Comment" name="submit" id="pc_submit">
      </p>
      </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the element with jquery

```
$('meta[http-equiv=refresh]').remove();
```

then put it back with jquery again when he's done typing...

```
$('head').append('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15;url=http://xyyyyyyy.com/testn.php">');
```

Comment: not working i have tried. can u please elaborate please or any demo if possible